# How to start learn linux device driver development?(worked on windows only)

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to learn Linux device driver development.

Positives:

1. I have developed small drivers on WinCE and worked on SPI, i2c interface from  application i.e. opening, reading and writing driver.
2. I'm good in operating system and data structures.

Negatives:

1. I have never worked on Linux.
2. My background is not embedded system.

How should I proceed to learn Linux device driver development?

EDIT: any book reference would be appreciable thanks

Comment: some codes added here. https://github.com/jeyaramvrp/kernel-module-programming

Answer (score 7):

Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition : http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/ should help you along.

Answer (score 1):

THE FOLLOWING LINKS WILL HELP TO START LEARNING DEVICE DRIVERS

http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux

http://lwn.net/Articles/driver-porting/